# Shiny reactive objects logic issue

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

My goal is to implement a Shiny app which shows several "problems" to the user with a list of possible answers, then lets the user choose an answer and stores it. Every problem has a previously stored answer that the user can overwrite.

I can't find a way to satisfy these two constraints at the same time with reactive objects:

- let the user select the next problem, with the answer being re-initialized from the previously stored answer
- store the answer for the current problem when the user selects a new answer (and only in this case)

Below a simplified code (no data, no loading/writing) which shows my current attempt. In this version the issue is that when a new problem is selected, the selected answer from the previous problem is immediately written.

```
library(shiny)

maxProblem=10

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Debugging test"),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           verbatimTextOutput("nbProblems"),
           uiOutput("ProblemSelection"),
           uiOutput("answerSelection")
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  
  

  output$ProblemSelection <- renderUI({
    numericInput("ProblemSelectionNo", 
                 "Select Problem no", 
                 value = 1, min=1, max=maxProblem)
  })
  
  
  currentProblemData <- reactive({
    print("calling loadCurrentProblemData")
    if (!is.null(input$ProblemSelectionNo)) {
      print("pretending to load data and previously stored answer for problem", input$ProblemSelectionNo)
      list( choices=c(1,2,3), answer=1)
    }
  })

    output$answerSelection <- renderUI({
    l<-currentProblemData()
    choicesList <- l$choices
    names(choicesList) <- l$choices
    radioButtons("answerInput", label = "Select answer",
                 choices = choicesList, 
                 selected = l$answer)
  })
  

  writeChanges <- observe({
    print('calling writeChanges')
    l<-currentProblemData()
    newAnswer <- input$answerInput
    prevAnswer <- l$answer
    if (!is.null(prevAnswer) && !is.null(newAnswer) && (newAnswer != prevAnswer)) {
      print(paste('Pretending to write new answer :',newAnswer,'for problem', input$ProblemSelectionNo))
      l$answer <- newAnswer
    }

  })

  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Before building everything on your own, maybe [`learnr`](https://github.com/rstudio/learnr) is suited for you?

Comment: @starja thank you for the great tip, I didn't know learnr and it looks much more convenient for this kind of task, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might have the functionality you are looking for. I made a workable example to try based on some of what you have.

First, I created a default list `choices_answer` which could flexibly store your default problem choices and answers. A `reactiveValues` list `lst` (`rv$lst`) will start with this, and then change as new answers are selected to store the new responses.

When a new problem is selected through the `numericInput`, then the `radioButtons` are updated based on the current answer for that problem (using the `rv$lst`). Likewise, when a new answer is chosen (or answer is changed), the `rv$lst` will be updated with the new answer for storage.

I also added output `ListData` to show what the storage of answers looks like as you make selections using the radio buttons.

```
library(shiny)

maxProblem = 5

choices_answer = list()
for (i in seq_along(1:maxProblem)) {
  choices_answer[[i]] <- list(
    choices = c("1", "2", "3"),
    answer = "1"
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Debugging test"),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           numericInput("ProblemSelectionNo", 
                        "Select Problem no", 
                        value = 1, min = 1, max = maxProblem),
           radioButtons("answerInput", label = "Select answer",
                        choices = choices_answer[[1]][["choices"]]),
           verbatimTextOutput("ListData")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(lst = choices_answer)
  
  observeEvent(input$ProblemSelectionNo, {
    updateRadioButtons(session, "answerInput", 
                       choices = rv$lst[[input$ProblemSelectionNo]][["choices"]], 
                       selected = rv$lst[[input$ProblemSelectionNo]][["answer"]])
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$answerInput, {
    rv$lst[[input$ProblemSelectionNo]][["answer"]] <- input$answerInput
  })
  
  output$ListData <- renderPrint({rv$lst})
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```